# How to run command in Rust

Tags: linux, rust

I want to run command in Rust?
I know `Command::new()`, but I have problems with running this command:
`nohup gdx-open ~/Documents &`.

Comment: What problems do you have?

Comment: `&` is part of the shell syntax, it makes no sense in a command. And `nohup` is also a shell thing (it protects the wrapped command against `SIGHUP`).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`nohup` and `&` are shell-specific constructs that tell your shell not to wait for the command to finish. They are not really part of your command at all, so what you want is:

```
let handle = Command::new("gdx-open")
                    .args(&["~/Documents"])
                    .spawn()
                    .unwrap();
```

If instead you wanted to wait for the command to finish before proceeding, you would use:

```
let result = Command::new("gdx-open")
                    .args(&["~/Documents"])
                    .status()
                    .unwrap();
```

or

```
let output = Command::new("gdx-open")
                    .args(&["~/Documents"])
                    .output()
                    .unwrap();
```

Moreover, the `~` is also a shell-specific construct which may or may not be understood by the command you're trying to run. It means "this user's home directory", which you can get from the `HOME` environment variable using [`std::env::var`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/env/fn.var.html):

```
let path = format!(
    "{}/Documents", 
    std::env::var ("HOME").unwrap_or_else (|_| "".into()));
let handle = Command::new("gdx-open")
                    .args(&[&path])
                    .spawn()
                    .unwrap();
```

And BTW, `~/Documents` is a special path, part of the [XDG user directories](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/XDG_user_directories) specification. Its actual location is platform-dependent and *language*-dependent (i.e. it gets translated depending on the user's configuration). It can also be overridden by the user. You might want to look at the [`directories`](https://crates.io/crates/directories) crate to get the correct value:

```
use directories::UserDirs;
let dirs = UserDirs::new();
let path = dirs
    .and_then (|u| u.document_dir())
    .unwrap();
let handle = Command::new("gdx-open")
                    .args(&[path])
                    .spawn()
                    .unwrap();
```

Comment: While `nohup` *can* be a shell builtin, and is nowadays mostly a workaround for shell behaviour (that closing a shell SIGHUPs its children, specifically the entries in its job table), technically it's not strictly shell-specific. It is completely useless here though.

Comment: The problem is that File Manages closes, after completing the command.

Comment: The `~` is also a shell thing, that expands to the home directory.